# EPERM error building Windows node.js Docker image on Azure Pipeline

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, npm-install, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run a node.js app in a Docker container on Windows Server. I have limited control over the server. Most notably, the server doesn't have Hyper-V available, so (I believe) I need a Windows-based Docker image. I have a Dockerfile that I can successfully build locally, but I'm getting an error when I try to build everything in an Azure Pipeline:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\app\package-lock.json'
```

I have verified (with `RUN dir`) that the file is successfully copied.

**Edit**
The pipeline works, on Azure as well as locally, if I don't copy over `package-lock.json`

Also of note (maybe), there's another error at the very beginning of the pipeline output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" pull "=installer c:\node\nodejs\ ."
invalid reference format
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" inspect "=installer c:\node\nodejs\ ."
Error: No such object: =installer c:\node\nodejs\ .
```

Though that might not be related as it appears to commence with building the image.

**Dockerfile**

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809 as installer

ARG NODE=16.3.0

RUN mkdir -p C:\node
WORKDIR C:\node

SHELL ["pwsh.exe", "-command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v$env:NODE/node-v$env:NODE-win-x64.zip -OutFile nodejsZip.zip -UseBasicParsing `
    && Expand-Archive nodejsZip.zip -DestinationPath .`
    && Rename-Item node-v$env:NODE-win-x64 nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

WORKDIR C:\nodejs
COPY --from=installer C:\node\nodejs\ .
ENV PATH="$WindowsPATH;C:/nodejs"
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json* npm-shrinkwrap.json* .npmrc .\

RUN dir

RUN npm install --production && move node_modules ..\

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Pipeline step**

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build and push Docker image
    inputs:
      command: buildAndPush
      repository: ***
      dockerfile: $(appDirectory)Dockerfile
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildId)
```

**Pipeline output**

```
Starting: Build and push Docker image
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, start or stop containers, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.187.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg
==============================================================================
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" pull "=installer c:\node\nodejs\ ."
invalid reference format
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" inspect "=installer c:\node\nodejs\ ."
Error: No such object: =installer c:\node\nodejs\ .
[]
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f D:\a\1\s\App\Dockerfile [bunch of labels with revealing names] -t ***/[appName]:1610 -t ***/[appName]:latest -t ***/[appName]:1.1.0 D:\a\1\s\App
Sending build context to Docker daemon  156.5MB

Step 1/30 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809 as installer
lts-nanoserver-1809: Pulling from powershell
b9043d31610e: Already exists
9385842e37a1: Pulling fs layer
1785b1708bde: Pulling fs layer
8bbda5f0e88c: Pulling fs layer
69aef7d2d307: Pulling fs layer
ce716bfd5dfd: Pulling fs layer
01ded93fffb2: Pulling fs layer
54121c5fa6ac: Pulling fs layer
3f8033467b82: Pulling fs layer
9e9e60715d2d: Pulling fs layer
69aef7d2d307: Waiting
ce716bfd5dfd: Waiting
01ded93fffb2: Waiting
54121c5fa6ac: Waiting
3f8033467b82: Waiting
9e9e60715d2d: Waiting
8bbda5f0e88c: Verifying Checksum
8bbda5f0e88c: Download complete
1785b1708bde: Verifying Checksum
1785b1708bde: Download complete
9385842e37a1: Verifying Checksum
ce716bfd5dfd: Verifying Checksum
ce716bfd5dfd: Download complete
69aef7d2d307: Verifying Checksum
69aef7d2d307: Download complete
54121c5fa6ac: Verifying Checksum
54121c5fa6ac: Download complete
3f8033467b82: Verifying Checksum
3f8033467b82: Download complete
9385842e37a1: Pull complete
9e9e60715d2d: Verifying Checksum
9e9e60715d2d: Download complete
1785b1708bde: Pull complete
8bbda5f0e88c: Pull complete
69aef7d2d307: Pull complete
ce716bfd5dfd: Pull complete
01ded93fffb2: Verifying Checksum
01ded93fffb2: Download complete
01ded93fffb2: Pull complete
54121c5fa6ac: Pull complete
3f8033467b82: Pull complete
9e9e60715d2d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2742181d6096061fa10b0b0ef34a00a634e7361f4948f4d71d99df052a08da64
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809
 ---> 4375ea1bb0a3
Step 2/30 : ARG NODE=16.3.0
 ---> Running in a129a7c48527
Removing intermediate container a129a7c48527
 ---> 6b07c85950b7
Step 3/30 : RUN mkdir -p C:\node
 ---> Running in 09f84ee6dbc8
Removing intermediate container 09f84ee6dbc8
 ---> 3400da58010d
Step 4/30 : WORKDIR C:\node
 ---> Running in 3406bcfdbc3e
Removing intermediate container 3406bcfdbc3e
 ---> 1957d042581a
Step 5/30 : SHELL ["pwsh.exe", "-command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in cb32ef99f0ec
Removing intermediate container cb32ef99f0ec
 ---> a39d5e0ae00e
Step 6/30 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v$env:NODE/node-v$env:NODE-win-x64.zip -OutFile nodejsZip.zip -UseBasicParsing     && Expand-Archive nodejsZip.zip -DestinationPath .    && Rename-Item node-v$env:NODE-win-x64 nodejs
 ---> Running in f693e5889205
Removing intermediate container f693e5889205
 ---> 88ac85fc56b9
Step 7/30 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
 ---> ad675c9cb2d5
Step 8/30 : WORKDIR C:\nodejs
 ---> Running in 07e5c75044bb
Removing intermediate container 07e5c75044bb
 ---> 985de76e022c
Step 9/30 : COPY --from=installer C:\node\nodejs\ .
 ---> 614424adca70
Step 10/30 : ENV PATH="$WindowsPATH;C:/nodejs"
 ---> Running in 54c7d7063723
Removing intermediate container 54c7d7063723
 ---> 06f449a12162
Step 11/30 : RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
 ---> Running in 88e0f906a572
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.15.1 -> 7.16.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.16.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.16.0` to update!
npm notice 
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.15.1 -> 7.16.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.16.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.16.0` to update!
npm notice 
Removing intermediate container 88e0f906a572
 ---> 37b0211fe99a
Step 12/30 : ENV NODE_ENV=production
 ---> Running in db15abf42b2e
Removing intermediate container db15abf42b2e
 ---> 1e1b5bfc11bf
Step 13/30 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in db460e099de7
Removing intermediate container db460e099de7
 ---> 5bcaea65c911
Step 14/30 : COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", ".npmrc", ".\\"]
 ---> 6f1ebb928f0d
Step 15/30 : RUN dir
 ---> Running in 117829a3f0f5
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1A2C-F251
 Directory of C:\app

06/04/2021  04:44 PM    <DIR>          .
06/04/2021  04:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/04/2021  04:42 PM             2,645 .npmrc
06/04/2021  04:42 PM         1,720,232 package-lock.json
06/04/2021  04:42 PM             3,101 package.json
               3 File(s)      1,725,978 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  21,299,695,616 bytes free
Removing intermediate container 117829a3f0f5
 ---> b51123956a61
Step 16/30 : RUN npm install --production && move node_modules ..\
 ---> Running in 8e47b2ad349e
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\app\package-lock.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\app\package-lock.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\app\package-lock.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\app\\package-lock.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-04T16_45_21_968Z-debug.log
The command 'cmd /S /C npm install --production && move node_modules ..\' returned a non-zero code: 4294963248
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 4294963248
Finishing: Build and push Docker image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the default user in `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809` is `ContainerUser`, a non-administrator account. I'm not sure the exact permissions Docker's COPY command uses on Windows containers. On Linux it creates files owned by `root` though, so something similar in Windows. Switching to the `ContainerAdministrator` user (`USER ContainerAdministrator`) for the npm install process fixed my permissions problems.